# What adverb (that isn't a participle) means eternal? (Eternally does Not work.)

Tags: single-word-requests

What adverb (that isn't a participle) means for eternal?  This adverb would only relate to eternal in time, and not necessarily infinitely in other ways. For example, "infinitely" means infinity in the quantity of intensity. The question is only about infinity in the quantity of time.

Everything below is extra information.

---

Eternally does not work because although it is based on eternal, it really means eternal from this point in time ([aka, forever](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/eternally)).  Eternal means forever without a beginning, and forever without an end (existing forever in both the past, present, and future). It is understandable why this exists. When one says, "I am eternally grateful for you," It would normally be weird for someone to be eternally grateful of someone before a particular event.

The usage of "eternally" with the forever meaning is much more frequent then its usage as eternal. However words' definitions are in their usage. The word "nice" formally meant silly, but I would suspect that you would side with the new definition of friendly. If it can be proven that "eternally" with the definition of eternal, is just as frequent as "eternally" with the definition of forever. Then eternally would be an answer.

---

Always doesn't work because always' means "on every occasion" (According to its [top definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/always)). Eternal doesn't care wheter it is time for an occasion or not. "In an eternal manor, I run late," literally means without any form of interruptions, even before the occasion starts.  "I always run late," means only when the occasion starts.

---

Forever doesn't work because forever means infinitely into the future (unless specifically said "forever into the past").

---

This is specifically related to modern usage. 500 years ago there were probably many words that would be an answer. However now those words mean more forever than eternal.

---

I am using this for "Truth [adverb] is all the following." and "I [adverb] infinitely strive." If you don't like the idea of eternal as an adverb being used for me (a finite being) striving, please only focus on the first example (or don't focus on any example).  I am not asking a philosophy question beyond the English language. Specifically I am asking because I am creating an affirmation, and I want the affirmation to be truth in an eternal manor. My usage of the word is to negate the present tense of the verbs (to include the past, present, and future.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I edited the question, is that better?

Comment: No. Context dictates usage to a greater degree than raw data about overall preponderance of usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed, but I'm using this for an affirmation.  And an affirmation either has no context or it has any context.

Comment: 'If it can be proven that "eternally" with the definition of eternal, is just as frequent as "eternally" with the definition of forever. Then eternally would be an answer.' is a wrong analysis. In using 'eternally yours', I doubt that one person in a million actually does a double check about three score years and ten, the afterlife ... But those using the phrase 'the eternal Father' will almost certainly have some notion of 'throughout all eternity' (and perhaps beyond) at least at the back of their minds. 'Truth eternal' connotes the 'through eternity' sense rather than the 'always yours'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'Truth eternal' absolutely means 'through eternity.' I say that in the post. I am worried about eternal**ly** which has a different definition. eternal**ly** would be modifying "is" not "Truth." Would "eternally is" mean the 'through eternity' or 'always yours?'

Comment: [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eternally) gives as its 'number 1' (default) definition for **eternal**: <<
adj.
[1] Being without beginning or end: _belief in an eternal creator_ >>, and 'eternally', listed underneath this, must be taken as having a corresponding principal sense. AHD lists the 
<< [2] 'earned my eternal gratitude' sense >> second (though ODO defines the usage better: << ... [2] [as submodifier] Used to emphasize expressions of admiration, gratitude, etc: _‘I shall be eternally grateful’_ >>.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. However The Free Dictionary says eternal means: "Being without beginning or end." One could definitely reasonably assume that leading to "eternally" meaning the same thing. However it does not specifically define "eternally" as without a beginning.

Comment: DO use comments to [ask for clarification, suggest changes, or offer short-lived information](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). DO NOT use them for minor edits ([edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) instead) answers (post an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebukes ([vote](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) instead), discussion ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), or comments on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on circumstance, **timeless** or **timelessly**
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/timeless

There is no end or beginning. It is timeless because it cannot be measured within time but exists independently of it.

I know you wanted the adverb, **timelessly**, but in the context that you wish to use it, I think the adjective may also work, e.g:

> "Truth timeless is all the following."

where I think it works very effectively to describe the noun 'Truth' and it alliterates nicely.

Comment: I can't find any definitions of timelessly that only mean forever, so I think this is the answer. I think timelessly works better since my usage of the word is to negate the present tense of the verbs.

Answer (score 1):

'Perpetual and perpetually' is what I use.

> Never ending or changing [The Oxford English Dictionary p1312]
>
> Origin : Middle English from Old French *perpetuel* from Latin *perpetualis* from *perpetuus* 'continuing throughout' from *perpes* 'continuous'.

My own understanding of this word 'perpetual' is that, in its origin and in its usage, it does not refer to time. It refers to a state which exists, irrelevant of time.

Comment: On online dictionaries it doesn't have perpetual as an adverb.  With perpetually, I think that has the same problem as forever.  I'm only seeing definitions of perpetually as ["never stopping"](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/perpetually). I would agree that perpetual and perpetually used to mean eternal, however currently this is not the case. I edited the question to include that point.